# Is Use of getApplicationContext() considered Harmful?

Tags: java, android

Yesterday I read that using getApplicationContext() was potentially hazardous. Thus, code like this:

```
Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "You mashed the button, dude.", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
```

...should be this instead:

```
Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "You mashed the button, dude.", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
```

(where "MainActivity" is the name of the class in which the code lives).

Yet I see many code snippets that include getApplicationContext(), such as:

```
button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
    public void onClick(View v) {
        _initTask = new InitTask();
        _initTask.execute( getApplicationContext() );
    }
});
```

...from [here](http://pastebin.com/5ZYw5wND). Is it really preferable to use `<className`>.this over getApplicationContext()?

### UPDATE

I've obviously still not understanding the niceties (or meanities) of this; with this code:

```
Toast.makeText(GetVendorsTask.this, s[0], Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
```

I get this compilation err msg:

*Error:(156, 18) error: no suitable method found for makeText(MainActivity.GetVendorsTask,String,int)
method Toast.makeText(Context,CharSequence,int) is not applicable
(argument mismatch; MainActivity.GetVendorsTask cannot be converted to Context)
method Toast.makeText(Context,int,int) is not applicable
(argument mismatch; MainActivity.GetVendorsTask cannot be converted to Context)*

So I changed the complained-about line of code to:

```
Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, s[0], Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
```

...and it works (compiles). `MainActivity` is the outermost class in the .java file (named MainActivity.java, that is); but `GetVendorsTask` is the most proximate class (that line of code is within the `GetVendorsTask` class). To be clear, the code is:

```
public class MainActivity extends ActionBarActivity {

    . . .

    class GetVendorsTask extends AsyncTask<Context, String, SearchResponse>
    {
    . . .
        @Override
        protected void onProgressUpdate(String... s)
        {
            super.onProgressUpdate(s);
            //Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), s[0], Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show(); <= "getApplicationContext()" might be null
            //Toast.makeText(GetVendorsTask.this, s[0], Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, s[0], Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
```

So replacing "GetVendorsTask" with "MainActivity" appeases the beast, but is it the best way to do it?

### UPDATE 2

[This](http://examples.javacodegeeks.com/core-java/json/json-parsing-with-gson/) sample code uses simply "this" in place of the other possibilities.

Comment: Hey Clay, what were the reasons given for application context being hazardous? Do you have a link to an article?

Comment: [I think the docs do a pretty good job of describing when to use it](http://bit.ly/1kvxajO)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The `Application` `Context` is a singleton class that will always return the same `Context` instance no matter where you are in your `Application`. In other words, the `Application` `Context` will persist for as long as your `Application` is running.

In the other hand, using an `Activity` for `Context` will be specific to that `Activity` and it is different than the `Application` `Context`. For example, you can use the `Activity` `Context` to show a `Dialog`, but not the `Application` `Context`.

[Here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7298955/2029566) is an answer that explains it in more detail.

Also, I cannot recommend [this](http://www.doubleencore.com/2013/06/context/) post enough; it clarified the topic for me quite a bit when I read it.

Answer (score 1):

It is best to pass in the minimum required `Context` for whatever you're doing.  Treating the application context as a kind of god object can temporarily hide problems arising from misuse of lifecycle methods.